# What does Repetition range replaceable by '*' mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I performed code analyzer in IntelliJ IDEA and it shows weak warning as

> Repetition range replaceable by '*'

Its shows warning on below line of code Where I'm using regex pattern

```
String pattern = prefix + ".{" + length + "}" + suffix;
```

I'm not sure whether my code will work after replace `.{` with `*`

Simplified version of code :

```
String code = "AUTONARNDATEST";

String prefix = "AUTO";
String suffix = "TEST";
String length = "6";
String pattern = prefix + ".{" + length + "}" + suffix;

if(code.matches(pattern)) {
    System.out.println("thumbs_up");
}else {
    System.out.println("thumbs_down");
}
```

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Do you know what `.*` does as opposed to `.{10}`(or whatever length is)?

Comment: I'd agree with you, it might break your code. `foo.{5}bar` is not the same as `foo.*bar`

Comment: What do you do with the pattern afterwards?

Comment: Are you trying to find `length` times of periods `.` or any character?

Comment: can you show us more code please? maybe there are some missing pieces in your question

Comment: @Kayaman,  System auto generates a coupon code with certain parameters like some prefix, post-fix and length So i have to validate whether coupon code generated with the given parameters

Comment: @YCF_L, Code updated

Comment: Which line does IntelliJ say has that problem?

Comment: @mattfreake `String pattern = prefix + ".{" + length + "}" + suffix;`

Comment: That warning is definitely incorrect. You want a certain number of "any character".

Comment: My $0.02: the code analyzer is either confused  or being overly cautious, or perhaps a little of both.  _You_ know you're doing the right thing (;->), so just ignore the warning and move on.

Comment: You can avoid it if you do `String pattern = String.format("%s.{%s}%s", prefix, length, suffix);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by analyzer in Intellij IDEA. This is the relevant part:

```
  @Override
  public void visitRegExpQuantifier(RegExpQuantifier quantifier) {
    if (quantifier.isCounted()) {
      final RegExpNumber minElement = quantifier.getMin();
      final String min = minElement == null ? "" : minElement.getText();
      final RegExpNumber maxElement = quantifier.getMax();
      final String max = maxElement == null ? "" : maxElement.getText();
      if (!max.isEmpty() && max.equals(min)) {
         ...........
      }
      else if (("0".equals(min) || min.isEmpty()) && "1".equals(max)) {
         ..........
      }
      else if (("0".equals(min) || min.isEmpty()) && max.isEmpty()) {
        myHolder.newAnnotation(HighlightSeverity.WEAK_WARNING, RegExpBundle.message("weak.warning.repetition.range.replaceable.by.0", "*"))
        .withFix(new SimplifyQuantifierAction(quantifier, "*")).create();
      }
       ...........
```

In this case it sees the string `.{`, and interprets it as a quantifier with both `min` and `max` ranges empty, because it cannot statically parse the content of `length` and minElement/maxElement.getText() return null. So it falls to the branch which produces the warning. If IDEA can statically parse `length`, then the warning does not come:

```
String length = "6";
String pattern = ".{" + length + "}";  // No warning
if ("a".matches(pattern)) ;
```

Compare with:

```
String length = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
String pattern = ".{" + length + "}";  // Warning, cannot statically parse length
if ("a".matches(pattern)) ;
```

As I mentioned in the comment you can avoid it if you produce the pattern with String.format:

```
String pattern = String.format("%s.{%s}%s", prefix, length, suffix);
```

Comment: Much appreciated! My team had resolved this warning a couple of separate times which led to crashing.